# Right triangle inside a right triangle

Tags: geometry

I have made this question but I am not able to solve it.

> We have a right triangle $ABC$ right angled at $B$ and $\angle BAC = 15^\circ$. From $B$, draw a segment $BD$ such that $D$ on $AC$ and then from $D$, draw $DE$ such that $\angle{BDE} = 90^\circ$ and $BE = AE$. Find angle $DEB$.

The figure:-
[image: Figure]

My attempt:-

Let angle $EDA$ be $\theta$.
Let $DB = x$ and $AB = 2y$ ($AE = EB = y$).

Using law of Sines in triangle $ABD$:-
$$\frac{x}{\sin(40)} = \frac{2y}{\sin(90 + \theta)} \tag 1$$
Using law of Sines in triangle $DEB$:-
$$\frac{x}{\sin(15 + \theta)} = \frac{y}{\sin(90)} \tag 2$$

From (1) and (2) :-
$$(y)\sin(15 + \theta) = \frac{(2y)\sin(15)}{\sin(90 + \theta)}$$

$$\sin(15 + \theta) = \frac{2\sin(15)}{\sin(90 + \theta)}$$

But I don't know how to solve for theta from here. (If I get theta then I will get the required angle)

Can someone provide a solution? I recommend not to use trigonometry because in class 10, we have just got an introduction to trigonometry. Not advanced trigonometry like law of Sines, half angle rule, etc.

But it will be okay if you use trigonometry, I will try to understand it.

Comment: "From B on AC draw a segment BD and from D on AC draw DE such that $\angle BDE = 90^o$" this statement is unclear. Can you please describe which point lies where?

Comment: @ Congruent: If not a typo, please roll back.

Comment: In your (partial) solution, you use the fact that $AE=EB$. It looks you have forgotten to mention this fact in the problem description...

Comment: @Intelligenci pauca See my comment above.

Comment: If $E$ is the midpoint of $AB$, then a solution can exist only if $\sin\angle BAC\le1/3$, which is not the case.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add one thing

Comment: Can you add a Geogebra drawing or so? I'm getting infinite solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In the light of changes to the problem by OP a second answer is given.

Right angles at the $D's$

Many ways to draw. No unique solution.

[image]

Comment: +1, my first thought, too.

Comment: @Narasimham please check, I have edited the question. Sorry for inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

The solution given here avoids trigonometry.

Analytical geometry is more convenient for the purpose.

Chosen a circle diameter 2 for convenience.

Circle tangent at  Origin $E (0,0);$ Diameter $EB=2$ units.

$$ (x-1)^2+y^2= 1,~ x^2-2 x +y^2=0 \tag 1 $$
Straight line

$$\tan 15^{\circ}= m; y= m x + 2 m \tag 2$$

Solve simultaneously for two intersections by a quadratic equation. An analytical solution is also possible. Numerical solution given:

EDIT 1:

Apologies for two typos in earlier answered numerical code ! Verified using ruler,compass and protractor construction.

```
a = 1; tn15 = Tan[Pi/12.];
Solve[{x^2 - 2 x a + y^2 == 0., y == tn15 (x + 2 a)}, {x, y}]
{{x -> 0.1903405601811801`, 
  y -> 0.5868999842496802`}, {x -> 1.407735651172136`, 
  y -> 0.9131000157503198`}}
ArcTan[0.1903405601811801`, 0.5868999842496802`] 180./Pi
ArcTan[1.407735651172136`, 0.9131000157503198`] 180./Pi
72.03133555073838`
32.96866444926162`
```

The required two angles $\gamma=\angle BED, \angle BEC=$ from red line slopes

$$ \tan \gamma_1=\frac{y_1}{x_1}, \tan \gamma_2=\frac{y_2}{x_2}, \tag 3$$

$$ \angle BED =\gamma_1\approx 72.0313^{\circ}, \angle BEC =\gamma_2\approx 32.9687 ^{\circ}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let
$A = (0,1), B = (0,0)$ and $C = (\tan(\frac{\pi}{12}),0)$ such that $\alpha$ is $15^\circ$.

An explicit form for the hypothenuse $b$, given $\alpha$ is 15°, is

$$y = \frac{-x}{\tan\frac{\pi}{12}}+1.$$

As OP asks for a solution without trig, we take the equivalent

$$y = 1 - \frac{x}{2-\sqrt3} \tag1$$

Let $k$ be a circle of radius $r=0.25$ centered at point $M = (0,0.25)$, such that it intersects the y-axis in $B$ and $E$, the midpoint of $AB$.

We have an explicit form for

$$k: x^2+(y-0.25)^2=\frac{1}{16} \tag2$$

Equating the hypothenuse and the Thales circle will give us the two intersection points $D_1$ and $D_2$ where $\angle BD_1E$ and $\angle BD_2E$ are $90^\circ$. Furthermore, it will give us $\angle CBD_1$ and $\angle CBD_2$, which are equivalent to the incoming angles at $E$. So, inserting (1) in (2) gives

$$x^2 + (0.75-\frac{x}{2-\sqrt3})^2=\frac{1}{16} \tag3$$

which is the quadratic

$$(8\sqrt3+1)x^2-(3+1.5\sqrt3)x+0.5=0$$

with the two solutions $x_1\approx 0.1467249960624$ and $x_2\approx0.2282750039376$. Inserting these values in either (1) or (2) will yield the y-values of our intersection points. We have

$D_1\approx(0.1467249960624, 0.4524148599547)$
$D_2\approx(0.2282750039376, 0.148066087207)$

As for the angles incoming at E, which are the angles outgoing at B, they are found with $\arctan \frac{y_D}{x_D}$, so we solve

$\theta_1=\arctan\frac{0.4524148599547}{0.1467249960624}≈72,03^\circ$
$\theta_1=\arctan\frac{0.148066087207}{0.2282750039376}≈32,96^\circ$